# How to correctly setup CHECK constraint with multiple LIKE statements?

Tags: t-sql, pattern-matching, sql-like

I am trying to enforce a simple rule for inserting values of bank_account column:

```
 - bank account can consist of only digits
 - bank account can have one hyphen '-' or zero hyphens
 - bank account can have one slash '/' or zero slashes
```

I have this check constraint:

```
alter table someTable
add constraint chk_bank check
(
    (bank_account not like '%-%-%')
    and
    (bank_account not like '%/%/%')
    and
    (bank_account not like '%[^0123456789\-/]%')
)
```

And I have these bank_account numbers (they are fictional):

```
12-4414424434/0987
987654321/9999
NULL
41-101010101010/0011
500501502503/7410
NULL
60-6000070000/1234
7987-42516/7845
NULL
12-12121212/2121
```

When enabling the constraint I get this error:

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "chk_bank".
The conflict occurred in database "x", table "someTable", column 'bank_account'.
```

I tried some select queries but I can't find the wrong numbers.

Is my check constraint written wrong? If so, how should I change it to match my requirements?
Does check constraint ignore NULL values or are these a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#pattern-matching-with-the-escape-clause), there is no escape character by default.  You must use the `escape` clause to signify that the backslash is the escape character:

```
...and bank_account not like %[^0123456789\-/]%' escape '\'...
```

Comment: Your right, but the OP's code doesn't use a `case` expression.

Comment: Adding `escape '\'` to the last condition worked, thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to check the logic is to select the conditions individually, e.g.:

```
select bank_account,
  case when bank_account not like '%-%-%' then 1 else 0 end as CheckHyphens,
  case when bank_account not like '%/%/%' then 1 else 0 end as CheckSlashes,
  case when bank_account not like '%[^0123456789\-/]%' then 1 else 0 end as CheckIllegalCharacters,
  case when bank_account not like '%[^0123456789\-/]%' escape '\' then 1 else 0 end as CheckIllegalCharactersWithEscape
  from YourTable;
```

It becomes clear that your last condition is failing. Adding an `escape` clause corrects the pattern.